# Como graficar un cilindro en python con matplotlib?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

estoy aprendiendo a usar **matplotlib** y he estado intentando crear un cilindro pero no encuentro ninguna formula ni metodo que me sirva hasta ahora.

Lo que llevo hasta ahora es esto:

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
from pylab import *
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np

y= np.linspace(-20, 20, 90)
x= np.linspace(-20, 20, 90)


x, y= np.meshgrid(x,y)
#La funcion que estoy buscando graficar
z= x**2+y**2
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7,7))
ax= fig.add_subplot(1,1,1, projection='3d')
ax.plot_wireframe(x,y,z,rstride=2,cstride=2,cmap='Blues')
ax.set_xlabel('X Label')
ax.set_ylabel('Y Label')
ax.set_zlabel('Z Label')
show()
```

lo que tengo hasta ahora lo he encontrado de tutoriales en youtube pero no he visto informacion concreta acerca de solidos en 3d. Se agradece la ayuda :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes probar usando `plot_surface`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10,8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

# grid del cilindro
x=np.linspace(-1, 1, 200)
z=np.linspace(-2, 2, 200)
Xc, Zc=np.meshgrid(x, z)
Yc = np.sqrt(1-Xc**2)


# Plot del cilindro en dos partes
ax.plot_surface(Xc, Yc, Zc, alpha=0.2, rstride=10, cstride=10) # Mitad delantera
ax.plot_surface(Xc, -Yc, Zc, alpha=0.2, rstride=10, cstride=10) # Mitad trasera

plt.show()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]